# React - useMemo has a complex expression - Extract it to a separate variable so it can be statically checked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to use `useMemo` but a I got a message from lint:

> React Hook useMemo has a complex expression in the dependency array. Extract it to a separate variable so it can be statically checked
>    react-hooks/exhaustive-deps.

What could it be?

```
const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState("Escolha uma data para pagamento");
const itens = useMemo(() => {
  if (!contrato.propostas || contrato.propostas.length == 0) return [];
  let dates = contrato.propostas.map(p => p.vencimento)
  dates = Array.from(new Set(dates)).map((item) => ({
    id: item,
    option: item
  }))
  if (dates.length === 1 && selectedDate !== contrato.filterByDate) setSelectedDate(dates[0].option)
  if (contrato.filterByDate && dates.find(d => d.id === contrato.filterByDate) !== -1) setSelectedDate(contrato.filterByDate);
  return dates;
}, [JSON.stringify(contrato.propostas), contrato.filterByDate, selectedDate])
```

`contrato` and `contrato.propostas` are objects.
`contrato.filterByDate` is a string.
I tried to find an open question but I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 6):

It's telling you to do this:

```
const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState("Escolha uma data para pagamento");
const temp = JSON.stringify(contrato.propostas);
const itens = useMemo(() => {
 // ...
}, [temp, contrato.filterByDate, selectedDate])
```

But i don't see why you're stringifying `contrato.propostas`. You never use the stringified version, so it's not actually a dependency. And as long as you're keeping your data immutable (as you should in react), then you just need to put contrato.propostas directly into the dependency array:

```
const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState("Escolha uma data para pagamento");
const itens = useMemo(() => {
 // ...
}, [contrato.propostas, contrato.filterByDate, selectedDate])
```

Comment: The only reason for using JSON.stringify is that kinda mimics a deep comparison behavior. In case contrato.propostas is an object with nested properties and the default shallow comparison of React is insufficient. (even though it's not so performant depending on the object structure!)

Comment: What's the point for this requirement? I'm fairly sure React can't tell the difference either way.

Comment: `What's the point for this requirement?` To make the code simple enough that eslint can statically analyze it. "statically analyze" meaning "figure out if there's a problem with the code without running the code".